# Требуется найти все строки с вхождением заданной подстроки

Tags: python, строки, pandas

Допустим, есть pandas.DataFrame о товарах на складе. 
Выбрать только те элементы, для которых в столбце 'Название' в строке присутствует 'фарш'.

Например, 'говяжий **фарш**' или '**фарши**рованный фазан'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на свой вопрос нашел здесь: https://davidhamann.de/2017/06/26/pandas-select-elements-by-string/

Использовал .str.contains()

Comment: Лучше добавьте пример в ответ, а ссылка будет дополнительная к нему

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее идиоматичный способ ([Series.str.contains(reg_expr)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)) вы уже указали в вашем ответе.

Пример:

Исходный DF:

```
In [367]: df
Out[367]:
                  name
0         говяжий фарш
1   котлета по-киевски
2  фаршированный фазан
```

boolean mask:

```
In [368]: df['name'].str.contains(r'\bфарш')
Out[368]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: name, dtype: bool
```

фильтрование по булевой маске:

```
In [369]: df[df['name'].str.contains(r'\bфарш')]
Out[369]:
                  name
0         говяжий фарш
2  фаршированный фазан
```

`\b` - специальный символ в RegEx, обозначающий границу слова

---

PS в случае если надо проверить удовлентворяет ли каждая строка в Series определенному RegEx шаблону лучше воспользоваться [Series.str.match(RegEx_pattern)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match)